# Generate PEM file for live application

Tags: ios, iphone, certificate, keychain

My application  is already  live then how to generted pem file using appstore production cerificate that is also enable APNS  in ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this [link](http://www.apptuitions.com/generate-pem-file-for-push-notification/), It describes the entire process of creating APNS certificate then downloading it and converting it to pem file.
Hope it helps :]